# Is there something equivalent to .equalTo(object)?

Tags: realm, realm-java

I'd like to write a function that deletes the given `RealmModel` from the `Realm`, opening and closing the `Realm`.

I'm having a hard time to query for the same object on the new `Realm` instance in this delete method. What would be the recommended way to do so? I do not even know how to get the Primary Key without manually overriding a method in each of my models.

Comment: `I do not even know how to get the Primary Key without manually overriding a method in each of my models.` that's probably because that's the way to do it.

Comment: Any reason you cannot just use the `deleteFromRealm` method? https://realm.io/docs/java/3.0.0/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html#deleteFromRealm--

Comment: I wanted to create a "thread-safe" delete method that would take an unmanaged object and based on the primary key, delete it from Realm. Now that I reflect on it, it seems like a quite bad idea in the first place and I should re-evaluate the scoping of my Realm instances´.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need manually implent thread-safe delete operation on your `RealmModel`.

You can listen for updates in your threads by [**Object notifications**](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#object-notifications)

> Realm supports object-level notifications. You may register a notification on a particular RealmObject in order to be **notified if the object is deleted**, or whenever any of the managed fields on the object have their values modified.